# loop through files in photo library doesn't find any file

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, photo

I'm trying to backup my 46k pictures from Mac Photos into a reasonable date & time based folder structure and file names to use in another program or to just easily access the files through finder. Thanks to StackOverflow help I did manage to do so by copying the Master folder out of the library and then run the script on that folder with a mv command, I kind of remained challenged and would like to figure out a proper solution:

I run into an error with the code not finding any files in the library:

- the space and the dot aren't the problem, tested it with "/Users/Jan/Desktop/Photos x.y"
- mdfind works for the photos library in terminal
- mdfind finds 170k files when running on /Users/Jan/Pictures, however, that would copy not only the original pictures from the library

```
#!/bin/bash
#ensure no errors with spaces in filenames
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
#define variables to count files and progress
x=0
y=0
#count files in Master (Original Pictures) directory
for file in `mdfind file -onlyin "/Users/Jan/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters"`
do
    x=$((x+1))
done
echo "$x files found"
#loop for all files in Master (Original Pictures) directory
for file in `mdfind file -onlyin "/Users/Jan/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters"`
do
    #get date and timestamp of creation date and define Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute & Second as variable for the filename
    D=$(mdls "$file" | grep ContentCreationDate | awk '{print $3, $4}')
    YYYY=$(echo $D| cut -c 1-4)
    MM=$(echo $D| cut -c 6-7)
    DD=$(echo $D| cut -c 9-10)
    H=$(echo $D| cut -c 12-13)
    M=$(echo $D| cut -c 15-16)
    S=$(echo $D| cut -c 18-19)
    #add a variable in case multiple files with same timestamp exist
    i=1
    #define path and create new folders if required: "One per month in every year"
    newdir=$(echo /Users/Jan/Desktop/Photos/Sorted/$YYYY/$MM/)
    mkdir -p $newdir
    #get file extension
    ext=$(echo "$file"|awk -F . '{print $NF}')
    #define path and name of new file
    newfile=$(echo $newdir$YYYY-$MM-$DD_$H-$M-$S.$ext)
    #add a loop to add variable i and increase i in case a file with the same timestamp already exists
    while test -f "$newfile"
        do newfile=$(echo $newdir$YYYY-$MM-$DD_$H-$M-$S_$i.$ext)
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    #copy file into new directory with new timestamp name
    cp -p "$file" "$newfile"
    y=$((y+1))
    echo "$y out of $x files completed"
done
exit
```

Comment: Is there any error message? Have you tried to run the script in debug mode (`-x `)?

Comment: Do you know you do not have to use `$( echo ···)`?: `newfile="$newdir$YYYY-$MM-$DD_$H-$M-$S.$ext"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html)?

```
exiftool -r -P -d "/path/to/new/folder/%Y/%m/img_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S%%-c.%%e" "-filename<createdate" "/path/to/existing/pictures"
```

This will put all pictures into a folder/naming structure broken down by year, month, time, and count using the create date of the photo. It will also remove the original.

I use this when I cleaned up my years of pictures and as I continue to import new ones. If the create date doesn't exist, then it will skip the file.